# Loading CakePHP Helpers

Tags: cakephp, load, helper, idioms

This is a multi part question.

**Background:**

I'm building my first site using CakePHP, and I like it so far.  I've got a DB setup, initial data loaded, and a few models, views, and controllers to interface with the data.

I've created a globally accessible function to create Add/Edit/Delete type image links in various areas.  It will be used across multiple views, so I need it accessible, essentially, everywhere.  The function is defined in `/app/config/bootstrap.php`. I was hoping to use the HTML Helper's `$html->image()` and `$html->link()` methods to facilitate this, but they're not available in `bootstrap.php` and I'm not sure how to load/access the HTML Helper where I've defined my function.

**Questions:**

1) Is this a reasonable/idiomatic place to define a function of this sort?

2) If this isn't the correct place to define the function, where should I define it?

3) If this is the correct place to define the function, how can I go about loading various CakePHP helpers?

Again, I am new to CakePHP, so please let me know if my question is unclear, and forgive my ignorance.  I've read/searched through a fair amount of the CakePHP documentation and while I can find plenty of references to loading helpers within Controllers via `App::import(...);` or `$helpers = array(...);`, I do not seem to have access to the App object and the `$helpers` member is specific to the `AppController` class, I assume.  I assume I'm going about this incorrectly, so please help me understand the Cake way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not the correct place for such a function (or more accurately, it goes against the MVC paradigm). A better approach would be to [create your own helper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1097/Creating-Helpers) for the function. Depending on the complexity of the links you could also use [elements](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1081/Elements).

As a rule of thumb only functions that are completely independent of anything else in the app should be in bootstrap.php, and even most of those would often be better somewhere else.